# Why am I getting "hPutChar: resource vanished" errors from simple Haskell networking code?

Tags: macos, sockets, haskell

I tried to run some sample code from the [Haskell "Simple Servers" wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_Servers) today:

```
import Network
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO

main = withSocketsDo $ do
    sock <- listenOn $ PortNumber 5002
    loop sock

loop sock = do
   (h,_,_) <- accept sock
   forkIO $ body h
   loop sock
  where
   body h = do
       hPutStr h msg
       hFlush h
       hClose h

msg = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 5\r\n\r\nPong!\r\n"
```

I'm doing this on a Mac with El Capitan installed.

When I tried to run this code using `httperf` as indicated on the web page, I got the following error messages on the console:

```
ep1: <socket: 29>: hPutChar: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
ep1: <socket: 29>: hPutChar: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
ep1: <socket: 29>: hPutChar: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
ep1: <socket: 29>: hPutChar: protocol error (Protocol wrong type for socket)
```

Different runs will give different numbers of these messages. Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug, or is this normal, expected behavior?

Comment: This basically means that your server closes the connection without completing the exchange; this should not be intended behavior. The wiki page you linked to says about this code: _«Relies on the runtime scheduler to wake up the main thread in a timely fashion»_. Maybe this is not always happening.

Comment: How did you compile your program? Did you use the `-threaded` runtime?

Comment: @Zeta Yes, I used `-threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N`.